# Your tenant is Disabled for this service. You are not permitted to use this cmdlet - Skype Online

Tags: powershell, office365, skype-for-business

I am running the following PowerShell command but getting error.
I have used my CSP credentials to connect to the Skype Online session.

```
Set-CsOnlineVoiceUser -Identity user@example.com -TelephoneNumber +12221115654654
```

Error is as following

```
Your tenant is Disabled for this service. You are not permitted to use this cmdlet.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-CsOnlineVoiceUser], BvdCmdletException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TenantNotEnabledPSTN,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.Bvd.SetVoiceUserCmdlet
+ PSComputerName        : adminca1.online.lync.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when no user is a valid "voice user" within your tenant.

You can verfiy this by running `Get-CsOnlineVoiceUser`.
The output will be

```
WARNING:  No more business voice user available for tenant <id>
```

without any user.

A valid "Voice User" must have

- at least Office 365 E3 License
- a "phonesystem" license (if not Office 365 E5)
- a PSTN Calling Plan (inland pstn calling 120 minutes for example)

more infos: https://products.office.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/voice-calling